# Argument out of range Rails 4 and bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, twitter-bootstrap-3, runtime-error

I'm using the [bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails](https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails) gem to let users store the `scheduled_date` of a `WorkOrder` in my application (a 'DateTime' property), but I'm getting an `argument out of range` error when the user submits the form to create the `WorkOrder`, and the date is very different than what was selected whenever the user pops open the edit screen. The funny thing is that it used to work, but I don't know what code could have changed to break it.

I added the required dependencies & included the proper directives in my CSS/JS files:

```
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.5.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
```

As far as I can tell, my code looks identical to the example on the documentation. Here's the snippet of my form:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :scheduled_date %>
        <div class='input-group date'>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
          <%= f.text_field :scheduled_date,  class: 'form-control input-lg', id: "service_date_picker" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('#service_date_picker').datetimepicker({
          icons: {
            time: "fa fa-clock-o",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
            down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
          }
        });
      });
  </script>
```

EDIT (forgot to add controller code - super simple):

**work_orders_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @work_order = WorkOrder.new(work_order_params)

  ... [it errors on the line above]
end
```

And my parameter whitelist:

```
def work_order_params
  params.require(:work_order).permit(:caller_name, :brief_job_details, :contract_price, :quoted_by, :job_description, :scheduled_date, :time_materials_details, :sheduled_time, :contact_name, :payment_method, :notes, :customer_id, :job_site_id)
end
```

And an example of the parameters that give the `argument out of range` error when I save the form:

```
work_orders_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"caller_name"=>"Justin", "time_materials_details"=>"", "contract_price"=>"", "quoted_by"=>"", "payment_method"=>"", "job_description"=>"", "scheduled_date"=>"05/23/2014 1:28 PM", "notes"=>""}}
```

Same as my `customers_controller.rb` where I have a nested form for a `WorkOrder` inside of the new customer form (everything else on that form works perfectly):

```
def create
  @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)

  ... [errors above]
end
```

The date and time saves correctly if it is within 24 hours of now, but even when it saves correctly, the date displays completely weird and unformatted in the text field when I go to edit that `WorkOrder`. For instance:

When I select the date from the date picker: `05/06/2014 10:28 AM`

When I edit the `WorkOrder`: `2014-06-05 10:28:00.000000`

Any ideas? Any preference for whether I should make that field a `Date`, `Time`, or `DateTime` (currently)? Right now, we're working in Central time zone, but that won't always be the case.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: where are you getting the error? in the controller? where is the controller code?

Comment: @UriAgassi: Added controller code as requested. It's not a problem with my strong parameter whitelisting method in my controller either so I didn't include that method.

Comment: Please help us help you! If you know the error is in the first line, don't you think the _values_ of `customer_params` and `work_order_params` are relevant

Comment: @UriAgassi Done. I'm not getting any `unpermitted attribute` errors so I didn't think it was a big deal. I'm 99% certain it's something to do with the format either the datepicker is sending or a weird way Ruby is saving the date. Not sure.

Comment: Whitelist is not the _values_! Give us a sample value that passes, and a sample value that fails (simply add `p work_order_params` before the first line, and show us the output)

Comment: @UriAgassi Posted as requested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Uri Agassi is right: it's the values that you're passing to create the `WorkOrder` that are the most relevant here.

Try putzing around with the [custom date formatting options](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example5) provided to you by `bootstrap-datepicker`. If you can get a format that looks good and is easy to parse on the backend, then you'll want to intercept that parameter before it goes to the model for validation.

Regardless of what you'll go with for date formatting on the client-side, you'll still want to parse it into a useable `Date` or `DateTime` object server-side in your controller. [Check out `DateTime#strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime). You can also call `#strptime` on `Date`.

Untested, but the idea is there:

```
def create
  order_params = work_order_params
  order_params[:scheduled_date] = Date.strptime(order_params[:scheduled_date],
                                                '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
  @work_order = WorkOrder.new(order_params)
end
```

Comment: Oh how I've missed you. That worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I'm just baffled that it used to work without needing any special formatting before going into the db, but whatever.

Comment: this wont work for me (rails 4.2.0). It wont let me intercept the param and format it before it tries to set it on attribute for some reason.

Comment: @Sean you can update the params in place before they are passed as a strong param. Check out this stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399046/how-to-make-changes-to-strong-parameters-change-to-lowercase

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the modifications from the Controller all together by updating the values in the model. I feel this is a much cleaner (and reusable) approach.

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base

  def scheduled_date=(date)
     begin
       parsed = Date.strptime(date,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
       super parsed
     rescue
       date         
     end
  end

end
```

Comment: I would have never come up with that on my own. Still getting used to MVC. Seems like there are always many places code could go. Never used `super` either. Always learning.

Comment: Does this work if `scheduled_date` is updated via update, or update_attribute?

Comment: @NickSilva I don't see why not

Answer (score 3):

It's me helped:
To file application.js writing to end file:

```
$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});
});
```

Comment: That seems like a much cleaner solution than having to hack my back end code to handle a front-end widget. I'll try that next time!

Comment: In my case, it was 'dd-mm-yy'.  Submits/saves ok.  The 4 'y's made it show 20152015 in the form.

Answer (score 2):

This plugin uses moment.js. Basically you need to choose the time format you would like.

example

```
$(function () {
 $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({format: 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm'});
});
```