# Strong Parameters in Rails ignores a parameter after the content is modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, strong-parameters

I have an issue with my usage of strong params in rails controller. Here's my code :

```
def request_params
  params[:req][:emails] = params[:req][:emails].delete(' ').split(/\r\n|\n|,/).reject(&:blank?).dup
  params.require(:req).permit(:emails, :body, :link, :other, :attributes)        
end

@request = Request.new(request_params)
```

When the Request object is created with request_params, `emails` parameter is for some reason ignored.

Is there any reason not to permit this parameter after the paramter was parsed?

I had to assign the email attribute explicitly in order to solve the issue:

```
@request.emails = params[:req][:emails]
```

but I would like to know if there is a clearer solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399046/how-to-make-changes-to-strong-parameters-change-to-lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you trying to manipulate the parameters before permitting them? You should modify it before/after saving in model.

In case you still want to do it, try something like this:

```
def request_params
  temp = params.require(:req).permit(:emails, :body, :link, :other, :attributes)
  temp[:req][:emails] = temp[:req][:emails].delete(' ').split(/\r\n|\n|,/).reject(&:blank?).dup
  temp.permit!
end
```